# How to use Google Maps API in Visual C# Forms Application?

Tags: c#, winforms, api, google-maps, desktop-application

I have decided to design a desktop forms application in Visual C# 2012 which will download google map images within user specified coordinate and zoom level. Actually, the target is to create offline map as jpeg. Later I'll have to join the downloaded images also! Can anyone please help me on this issue?

Note: I will not display any web page. I just want to download the direct image from google maps as per specification on zoom level and coordinate.

Regards.

Comment: don't forget, you'll have to have copyright text all over your static map. Check out the [guidelines first](http://www.google.com/permissions/geoguidelines.html)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Have you checked GMap.NET? "Great Maps for Windows Forms and Presentation"

- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32643/GMap-NET-Great-Maps-for-Windows-Forms-and-Presenta
- http://greatmaps.codeplex.com

Comment: Glad it helped. If you find the answer useful you can accept and/or upvote it. Thanks

Comment: Not got enough points yet. I must vote my answer. Thanks a lot for good advice!

Comment: Hi again, you are welcome. "I must vote my answer" What do you mean? Anyway, since you are new here maybe you want to check: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235.

Comment: Lol! Today I found what I have written! I meant that I must vote useful answer to my question! Sorry!